# Add readonly comment to CSV file

Tags: java

Is there any way so that I could add read only Comment to a CSV file?

What I am looking is, I want to add a some version value to CSV file and want it to be read only so that when I send this file anybody he/she will be able to see that version without altering it.

Please help me..

Sorry if you do not understand the question. **Here is the detailed explanation..**

Suppose I am writing one csv file with my application and I want to assign my application's version to the csv file so that when I send this csv file to others on the network. Now they should be able to recognize the application's version assigned to that csv file. Its like assigning metadata to csv file.

I can do that with the help of Java's UserDefinedAttributeView class but I am not able to find that attribute anywhere in that file's "Properties" **(file=>Right-Click=>Properties)** details.

I hope this the expected detials about question.

Comment: There is no way to prevent someone to alter a file. The only thing you could do is check is the file have been modified.

Answer (score 2):

In short: No!

A CSV is just a plain text file which doesn't support features like read only sections.

Comment: I guess so but I think there should be something we can use to achieve this....anyway thax for reply...@André Stannek